# What is my recourse to edits that change the sense of my contribution?

Tags: discussion, support, editing

One of my answers was edited today in a way that greatly altered the tone of my words. I take my words seriously and if I'd wanted to write something else I would have. If I wanted my words to leave a different impression, I would have.

In this particular case the edit was done by someone who has a very different approach to the use of this forum, and I suspect a very different approach to life in general, than I do.

I have no problem if someone fixes a typo. This went way beyond that, to someone changing the tone and feeling of my words to suit his own personal worldview.

It seems clear to me that if someone doesn't like the way I write, they are free to neg me and/or *not read my answers*. I most definitely object in the most strenuous manner to being edited simply over a matter of personal style.

What is my recourse? And whose bad idea was it to allow a user who seems to have a personal issue with my writing style (and who frankly hasn't been around here that long) to edit my posts and change my tone and writing voice?

Comment: Edit your post back into a state you consider good? Accept what's good and change what you don't like

Comment: My removal of the tag here is primarily to indicate that this post isn't in current review by the staff of the site. If this is still an issue y'all are experiencing, please feel free to continue discussion.

Answer (score 3):

The edit in question: https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/revisions/22297/2

Your post was not edited 'in a way that greatly altered the tone of my words'. Your post was:

> Émile Durkheim.
>
> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sacred%E2%80%93profane_dichotomy
>
> Software says I need more character. Oh wait characters!

This does **not** fit the standards of this site. See: https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/referencing
**I edited your post to make it fit these standards.** What did I do?

- Removed useless text
- Added quote from link

> Émile Durkheim.
>
> > The sacred–profane dichotomy is an idea posited by French sociologist Émile Durkheim, who considered it to be the central characteristic of religion: "religion is a unified system of beliefs and practices relative to sacred things, that is to say, things set apart and forbidden."
> >
> > <sub>From: [Sacred–profane dichotomy on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sacred%E2%80%93profane_dichotomy); the quote from Durkheim 1915, p. 47</sub>

There is nothing wrong with that. In fact it is the very reason why I have been given the privilege through votes to edit posts. But even a suggested edit like this would've been accepted easily.

---

You then write:

> In this particular case the edit was done by someone who has a very different approach to the use of this forum, and I suspect a very different approach to life in general, than I do.

This is not a forum. This is a Q&A-site.
But anyway, who did the edit is not so important. You should look at edits objectively, no matter who does them. See for yourself if it makes the post better or not. This paragraph is irrelevant.

> I have no problem if someone fixes a typo. This went way beyond that, to someone changing the tone and feeling of my words to suit his own personal worldview.

As said before, I didn't make it fit my own worldview. I made it fit the standards. You have no reason to claim that editing in a quote from another webpage you linked to changes the meaning of the post.

> I most definitely object in the most strenuous manner to being edited simply over a matter of personal style.

Then maybe this is not the right site for you.

> What is my recourse? And whose bad idea was it to allow a user who seems to have a personal issue with my writing style (and who frankly hasn't been around here that long) to edit my posts and change my tone and writing voice?

I do not have a personal issue with your writing style.

I have been around longer than you (2y 2m versus 1y 3m). I was gone for a year though because I was doing other things. But if you have a look at my other accounts you can see I'm not only active here but also on other SE sites, which gives me a reason to think that I know a bit what fits the standards and what does not. But again, this shouldn't really matter in the context of an edit.

Comment: I looked through his answers to find the one that "altered the tone" of his words, but I saw that and thought no way that could be it. Really? @user4894, is this the edit you are referring to?

Comment: It is not clear from the answer how to determine what part of the text is useless and should be removed as such according to the standards of this site. It is very important for either asking questions or providing answers, and is left vague in this answer, could you please explain it more clearly?

Comment: No. This question was about one specific edit. I didn't intend to make any strict, general rules. What to edit is extensively discussed on Meta.SE and for the rest common sense, I won't repeat what has been said before.

Comment: The reason of my comment is exactly that it is certainly not common sense for me. Please believe, I am not being stubborn or intentionally not willing to understand, I really need more information on when exactly will a piece of my post be commonly considered as useless and needed to be removed as such.

Comment: This question here is about a specific answer, so you won't find the answer here. There are many posts on Meta.SE on this topic. I'm on my phone now so it's a little difficult to give you links, but if you search yourself you'll find plenty of good resources there. You have also just asked a question on this meta, so I think it's better to discuss the matter there rather than here.

Comment: That question does not concern editing, it concerns citing external sources. I would be grateful if you could provide some links to what you have in mind  when and if it will be easy for you to do it.

Comment: And this question is about one particular edit, **your comments are off topic here**, so this will be my last reply: http://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=when+should+I+edit+

Answer (score 1):

If you feel a change to your post has altered your intended meaning, you should be able to rollback any edits that were made, or, further edit the post to re-convey an intended message. Also, if someone below 1000 reputation suggests too many edits which are rejected, they will be banned from editing for 7 days. Above 1000 rep, edits are immediately applied but can still be rolled back at any time.

See: [Why can people edit my posts? How does editing work?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/editing)